# Windows Phone SDK 7.1 DirectX issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, directx

Tried to install Windows Phone SDK 7.1 with the Web Platform installer, but it was always unsuccessfull. I manually located the setup file and ran it. After the installation completed it showed a message:

> Setup could not install the following components:
>
> DirectX Libraries
>
> DirectX SDK Libraries

I am having issues with DirectX on my computer, the thread with more details is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/420518/directx-is-missing):

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.

If you are installing Windows phone 7.1 SDK in Windows 7 it should install. If it doesn't then  You do not have DirectX 10.0 support in your computer. Windows phone 7.1 SDK requires DirectX 10.0 support. Solution is to upgrade your Graphics card.

Comment: In the other thread I have mentioned that the actual direct x of the computer is 11.